# Angular material select for capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara, angular-material

Can I make select in RoR RSpec + Capybara?
Usually i use:

```
select 'something', from: 'select_name'
```

But for angular's `md-select` is doesn't work.
Capybara show error:

`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find select box "select_id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Riddler's solution wasn't finding the option. I rewrote it using CSS selectors and was able to get it to work:

```
def md_select(name, from:)
  find("md-select[name='#{from}']").click
  find('md-select-menu md-content md-option div', text: name).click
end
```

And usage is like so, with the *display value* of the option (not the value attribute):

```
md_select "Female", from: 'gender'
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple add a custom `md_select` method to Capybara.

```
def md_select name, from: ''
  puts 'md_select `from:` param is required. For example `md_select select_value, from: select_name`' if from.blank?

  find(:xpath, "//md-select[@name='#{from}']").click
  find(:xpath, "//md-select-menu/md-content/md-option/div[text()='#{name}']").click
end
```

And now we can use it in RSpec:

```
md_select select_value, from: 'select_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing an Angular Material interface with RSpec/Capybara for a while now so, I made a [capybara-angular-material gem](https://github.com/rimian/capybara-angular-material) that implements a DSL. I'm using the [poltergeist driver.](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist)

See:

- https://github.com/rimian/capybara-angular-material
- https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara-angular-material

It works like this:

`md_select('Something', from: 'select_label')`